# Gráfico com Google Charts

Tags: php, mysql, google-charts

Como posso fazer para preencher este gráfico, com dados do MySQL?

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM historicos';
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Horario', 'Sales'],
      ['2004',  0.500],
      ['2005',  0.1],
      ['2006',  0.200],
      ['2007',  0.30]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

---

Após alguns ajustes funcionou..
`
function drawChart() {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Horario', 'Tempo de resposta'],
                                
                                ]);

`

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! O que já tentou fazer? Assim a sua pergunta está muito ampla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basta substituir

```
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Horario', 'Sales'],
  ['2004',  0.500],
  ['2005',  0.1],
  ['2006',  0.200],
  ['2007',  0.30]
]);
```

por algo assim

```
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Horario', 'Sales'],
  <?php 
    $sql="sua query";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      echo "['".$result['campo1']."', '.$result['campo2']."'],";
    }
  ?>
]);
```

claro isso em um arquivo php

Comment: Não funcionou, ficou assim..

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Horario', 'Tempo'],
  <?php 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM historicos';
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      echo "['".$result['Data'].', '.$result['Tempo']."'],";
    }
  ?>
]);

Comment: executa seu php no navegador e olha o codigo fonte como fica e posta qui para eu ver por favor

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, sou novo aqui no stackoverflow, como posso colocar o fonte aqui?

Outra coisa, ele esta carregando os dados no godigo fonte, agora só não esta mostrando o grafico..

Comment: edita seu post original faz um traço la delimitando o post e das novas informações e posta ocmo bloco de cod

Comment: Funcionou, exatamente como você enviou, só fiz alguns ajustes...

Comment: Só não sei como posto as informações..

Comment: legau que bom que funcionou , clika no V ali no meu post par adar como concluido. para postar um bloco de código vc poe o simbolo de craze seu codigo craze dai fica assim `codigo`
voce tbm pode usar o site pastebin.org para postar o cod fonte do seu site e dai vc poe o link aqui.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado.. Abraço.